# Why or how to stop FullPage.js moving the current slide when closing lightbox

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js, featherlight.js, fancybox-3

I'm working with Fullpage.js with no issues on it's own.

I have a fairly basic setup; 5 full screen sections, three of which are sliders. All good.

Where I'm having issues is implementing a lightbox solution. I have tried various plugins such as featherlight and fancybox. These also work as expected. No problem. Until you close the lightbox.

When you close the lightbox, the current slide will slide half of the screen.

I've monitored what's happening in the console, and in the DOM. All I can see that could be creating this issue is that the lightbox html is being added, then taken away and this may be causing fullpage.js to reevaluate the document? This is guess work and doesn't really say anything, I know...

Another thing to note: The css transform set on the slide container that animates the slide is set to `0px, 0px, 0px` when the slide is properly in view. When the lightbox close button is clicked the transform is still the same yet the whole slide container has shifted.

It's happening on clicking the lightbox close button and clicking in the background so I know for sure it's not to do with accidentally click the slide right trigger.

---

As mentioned previously. I have a very basic setup, essentially following the docs of plugins used and on their own they are working, and together they are working, apart from the issue outlined above.

---

I've tried using the following:

1. `$.fn.fullpage.destroy();` upon opening an image.
2. `$.fn.fullpage.reBuild();` upon closing the lightbox.

This didn't work. It may be a complete misunderstanding of the reBuild method on my part but I assumed the page would be rebuilt from where it was. Instead what happened was that fullpage.js was no longer initialised on the page.

Also tried the following in the hope I could force the slide to reposition upon closing the lightbox:

1. Calling `$.fn.fullpage.silentMoveTo('my-section', 2);` on lightbox close.

This had no effect, the issue of the slide moving to half the screen position still happened.

---

I don't perceive this to be an implementation issue as everything is essentially working and, perhaps not a bug either, but it seems like featherlight or fancybox would work with fullpage.js

---

**Additional Info**

The slide I'm having these issues on, has a height, higher than the viewport.

I have the `scrollOverflow` option set to true, which in this case fires up iScroll.

I'm also setting the slide to `$.fn.fullpage.setAllowScrolling(false);` when viewing the slide.

Comment: I created a quick demo and it works fine - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LeNGmq?editors=1010 So, without seeing your page or any other live demo, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: Thank you for putting the demo together. It appears the issue is due to the Lightbox slide had more height than the viewport, causing iScroll to kick in. I've resolved the height to 100% viewport and everything is working as expected.

Comment: That was me rushing to have this working again. Although I can control the height in some cases, in others I can't so I'm still looking to resolve the issue. Question updated.

Comment: Maybe try setting `backFocus: false` for fancyBox. I can not image other reason. I have updated demo with horizontal navigation and it just works fine. Again, any demo would help.

Comment: Thank you very much Janis, that fixed it!